# upgrade log4j 1.2.17 to log4j2, NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog

Tags: log4j2

Actions about upgrade:
before this time log4j big bug. we arrange upgrade upgrade.
Jars i used:
log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar
log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
I use the bridge log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar for little change. but when i call my app,
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog hit this issue.
actually,there is no the class in the log4j-1.2-api.

I have tried to find the usage of FileWatchdog, but no any result.
pls help what can i do to fix or avoid this issue?

Comment: You must have left a copy of Log4j 1.2 in your classpath. **Remark**: the `log4j-core-2.8.2.jar` that you upgraded to, has a security vulnerability.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, Hi PiotrP, if i left Log4j 1.2 in my classpath, seems my upgrade actions will be meaningless

Comment: Finally, i got the answer.
there is a Log4jInitializer in my web.xml. need to remove it , the log4j will auto find the log4j2.xml. so the program will not load FileWatchdog in log4j1.2.17.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i got the answer. there is a Log4jInitializer in my web.xml. need to remove it , the log4j will auto find the log4j2.xml. so the program will not load FileWatchdog in log4j1.2.17.